# Break out of JavaScript data context to perform XSS when backslash and quotes are replaced?

Tags: xss, javascript

Suppose I have a this on my site:

```
<script> var x = "<? echo unsafe_data; ?>"; </script>
```

This is obviously vulnerable to XSS. Now suppose I "clean" the unsafe data by replacing `\` with `\\` and `"` with `\"` (in that order). Am I still vulnerable? What payloads could be used to escape from the JavaScript data context and execute code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
</script><script>alert('xss');</script><script>/*
```

?

JS parser will find the close `script`, and assume the original code is malformed. HTML parser will see the open `script` and start a new script block. The rest is just to make the rest of the block ignored.

Note that it doesn't contain any of the characters you're escaping - it shouldn't be affected by your sanitising code.

Comment: That works! Thanks for explaining it. Do you think there are other possible exploits as well?

Comment: Oh, probably, yes. Most limited filter methods have multiple flaws, often relating to switching contexts - in this case, from Javascript to HTML and back. What about `//` as an input string, for example?

Comment: That just ends up in the variable for me. It does not create a comment, if that was the intention. But it sounds reasonable that there should be many other exploits anyway.